# Late filing Returns from 2015, 2016 and now 2017. With income in 2015 and 2016, but NOL in 2017

Tags: united-states, income-tax, amended-tax-return

What is the procedure for filing these late returns?  Do I file the returns and then file an amended return to show the carry back from the loss from 2017?

2015 AGI $143,567 - after ID and Exemptions - TI of $84,669.
2016 AGI $162,566 - after ID and Exemptions - TI of $94,429.
2017 AGI ($160,022)

Can I claim credits for 2017?  Child Tax Credit, etc,

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Given the amount of money involved, I'd be asking a CPA, not the internet.

Comment: +1 to ceejayoz. CPA or tax lawyer or both.